# My JavaScript Validation Form Wont Recognize Filled Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to code a validation or registration form that requires a Name, 2 Matching Passwords, and an Email. As of right now I'm hung up on the alert that pops up if the Name Input (which I styled using a div) is empty. We're supposed to be using mostly If/Else functions.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<body>
<div id='register'><p>Register Here:</p></div>
<div id='background'>   
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="A" ></input> 
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="B"></input>  
<input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="C"></input>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="D"></input>
</div>
<input type="Submit" id="button"></input>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var Name = $('A').val();
var Pass = $('B').val();
var Confirm_Pass = $('C').val();
var Email = $('D').val();

$('#button').click(function(){    
if(!Name){
  alert("Fill in all boxes");
}
else{
  alert('valid');
}  

});
});
```

What happening as of now is that I'll receive the alert "Fill in all boxes" even if the input is filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/p6hYa/

There are few issues here noted in the comments below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Selecting by ID is in the form $("#ID")
    var Name = $('#A'); //You want to get the values AFTER submit is clicked, otherwise this will always be the initial empty value.
    var Pass = $('#B');
    var Confirm_Pass = $('#C');
    var Email = $('#D');

    $('#button').click(function(){    

        if(!Name.val()){ //Inside the click event you grab the value
          alert("Fill in all boxes");
        }
        else{
          alert('valid');
        }  
    });

});
```

Comment: You have made my day that much better. As you can probably tell, I'm new to this whole coding thing. So obviously that helped a lot.

Comment: @user3602250 - You're very welcome and I'm glad it helped. There are links to many helpful resources in my profile if you're interested. Good luck and keep learning :D

Comment: The other part to this is getting the Passwords to match. I have: 

    `if(!Confirm_Pass.val() != Pass.val()){
      alert("Passwords Arn't Matching");
    }else{
      alert('valid');
    }`

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle example with checking passwords: http://jsfiddle.net/p6hYa/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('A')
```

Will search for

```
<A></A>
```

You are looking for

```
$("#A")
```

Comment: It seems I should look further next time, Chase has found a second issue I didn't notice.